# How do I change my footer information?

Tags: php, footer

I have a website that I am trying to edit, but only have it available on my localhost WAMP server, so I can not link to the site. The footer has wording that I would like to change, but my footer file only shows the following:

```
    <?php PC_Hooks::pc_after_opening_footer_tag(); /* Framework hook wrapper */ ?>
    <?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); // Adds support for the four footer widget areas ?>
    <?php PC_Hooks::pc_before_closing_footer_tag(); /* Framework hook wrapper */ ?>

    </footer>
</div><!-- #body-container -->

<?php PC_Hooks::pc_after_closing_footer_tag(); /* Framework hook wrapper */ ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not know where to find the file that I need to change.  I have litterally gone through every file and can not find where it determines what it shows in the footer. I am not completely familiar with PHP, but can generally figure out at least which file needs to be edited. Can anyone help me understand where I might be able to find the file to edit to change the wording in my footer??

Comment: have you got a function external file containing any objects, constants etc?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I feel really stupid now. I figured it out almost immediately after posting this question... It's a wordpress theme, and the option to change the footer information is in the theme options. Still don't know where the file is, but I figured out how to do what I need to do.

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted. You can answer you own question in case anyone else has the same problem.